# Creating Windows form containing subform

Tags: .net

I am trying to create an `OrderHeader` form which will contain the subform `OrderDetail`. The user can input data about the order header (date, customer, etc.), and in the subform, they will be able to input as many rows they like (I plan to use a datagrid view). You can see the relationship between these tables below:

[image]

I am confused about how to "connect" these two data sources on one form. I plan to create a form based on the OrderHeader table and then to drag and drop the datagridview object which will contain the source from the OrderDetail table. Even if I manage to connect them, do I have to modify the main code for saving data that currently looks like this:

```
Me.Validate()
Me.OrderHeaderBindingSource.EndEdit()
Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.BazaDataSet)
```

Comment: Can anyone help me  with this? Thank you. Adi

Comment: These videos helped me solve it,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rGiOkUc1tLE
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qo4Zkr1ZVic

Best regards,
Adi